# Stuck with custom URL REWRITE

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm creating a custom url rewrite structure for my WordPress site.

First I had the following code to have url: `/objekt/<GID>` which loads `objekt` page and have query var **GID**.

```
add_action( 'init', 'objekt_url_rewrites_init' );

function objekt_url_rewrites_init(){
add_rewrite_rule(
        'objekt/([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=objekt&GID=$matches[0]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'objekt_url_query_vars' );
function objekt_url_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'GID';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Now, I need to change URL structure to `/en/objekt/<GID>`. So, I change

```
objekt/([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/?$
```

to

```
en/objekt/([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/?$
```

But its not working!

When I visit `/en/objekt/<GID>` it just redirects to  `/en/objekt/` and not getting any query var named **'GID'**

Comment: What do you mean by _"its not working"_. Do you get an error? Is the URL rewrite not working?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I've updated the question. The page is redirecting from `/en/objekt/<GID>` to `/en/objekt/`

Comment: Figure out what is doing that redirect. Disable all other rewrite rules. If it's still redirecting it's your code doing the redirect.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I've not added any other rewrite rules to WP. All are defaults

Comment: Well, something is wrong. I'm just going through the debugging steps.

Comment: on your above code you are lefting out en/ should it be `'en/objekt/([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/?$',` or if u want both `'(en/)?objekt/([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/?$',`